# Создание windows forms

Tags: c++, winforms, visual-c++

Стоит visual studio 2015 desktop. Хочу создать приложение visual c++. Создаю пустой проект С++, потом ПРОЕКТ -> создание нового элемента, дальше ищу windows forms, а ее нет, UI вообще нет. Как создать форму?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проекта Windows Forms для языка С++ в VS нет. Если уж так приспичило писать GUI на плюсах то можно поучить MFC (но это, ИМХО, еще тот геморрой). Вообще рекомендуется для GUI использовать либо С# либо Basic, тогда у вас будут в распоряжении и WinForm и WPF. А часть логики которую будете писать на плюсах можно вынести в отдельную библиотеку.

Comment: `WinForms` есть для `c++/cli`. Но об этом можно сказать примерно так же как уже сказано про MFC :)

Answer (score 0):

А если поискать, то есть - http://mvblog.ru/archives/861 или вот видео: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a7XPMLbnpU0 . Много и других ссылок...

Дело в том, что, начиная с VS 2012, в списке проектов, которые можно создать, убрали пункт Приложение Windows Forms. Однако тот факт, что такой проект нельзя выбрать из списка, не говорит о том, что его нельзя создать самому.

Comment: `WinForms` это `.Net`, а под `.Net` используются управляемые языки, т.е. не `c++`, а `c++/cli`, но это не одно и то же.

Comment: Я и без вас знаю, что можно так делать. Но когда создаешь новый элемент, нету пунктфа UI. Я же все расписал

Comment: Ну вроде как в скинутых ссылках преведено, как всё это настроить